# Double quoting command string beyond /k flag

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm updating a batch file that originally had a variable for an executable like so:

`set var=C:\SomeProgram\program.exe`

I was able to run the program from the batch file correctly using the following syntax for cmd.exe:

`start "" cmd /k %var% "%param1%" "%param2%"`

Had to move some things around on the network and now the variable is as such:

`set var=D:\Some Group\3. Team Number\SomeProgram\program.exe`

The spaces and `\` tend to cause issues depending on the combination, to which I know is solvable by enclosing the variable with `""` like so: `"%var%"`. However, when I try to run the command:

`start "" cmd /k "%var%" "%param1%" "%param2%"`

I get: `D:\Some is not recognized as an internal...yada yada...`. Through some debugging:

`start "" cmd /k "%var%"` runs the application

`start "" cmd /k ""%var%" "%param1%" "%param2%""` runs the application

Why is that I now need to include the surrounding `""` to the entire command string when I didn't have to before simply because the application endpoint location is now enclosed with `""`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmd.exe` can be very quirky. If you type `cmd /?`, the following paragraph from its output explains it all:

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

    1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
        on the command line are preserved:

        - no /S switch
        - exactly two quote characters
        - no special characters between the two quote characters,
          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
        - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
          two quote characters
        - the string between the two quote characters is the name
          of an executable file.

    2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
        a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
        remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
        any text after the last quote character.
```

In your case, the conditions for treatment 1 are not all satisfied, so treatment 2 is used. In `cmd /k "%var%" "%param1%" "%param2%"`, the first and last quotes are removed, ending up in the incorrect `cmd /k %var%" "%param1%" "%param2%`. Adding quotes around the whole line after `/k`, as you did, solves the problem.